# How does perl recognise end of variable while printing?

Tags: perl

How does perl recognise end of variable?

For example, this code:

```
use warnings;
my $a = 10;
print "Value of a is $a:::";
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $a:: in concatenation (.) or string at tryprint.pl line 6.
Value of a is :
```

Why does it consider $a:: and not $a: or $a:::

This works:

```
print "Value of a is $a\:::";
```

prints:

```
Value of a is 10:::
```

Comment: In the general case, anything that can be used in a variable name is interpreted as being a variable name after `$`.  If you want to disambiguate, use braces; say, to print `$a` followed by `b`, use `print "${a}b"` (rather than `print "$ab"` which would look for, and probably fail to find, a variable named `$ab`).

Comment: oh, `Perl`: `print "$parts_$of_$file_$name"`  :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`::` is used to print/access a variable from a package/symbol table. For eg, to access a scalar variable x in package abc, Perl uses  `$abc::x` where `abc` is the name of the symbol table and `x` is the variable.  Similarly, when you used `$a:::`, Perl thought there is a package whose name is '`a`' and the variable name as `:`, and hence those error.

See this example below:

```
our $a = 10;
{
        my $a=20;
        print "lexical a is $a \n";
        print "Value of a is $main::a";
}
```